# Only able to edit one time in one cell/column in datacontrolgrid

Tags: c#, wpf, xceed, datagridcolumn

I have a datacontrolgrid which has three columns and is bound to a list and also has a clickevent (but i need to combine this with a key on the keyboard to be be able to edit the selected cell/column). I only want to edit one of these columns and therefore have a EditTemplate in that specific column tag in xaml-file with a datatemplate containing a textbox with a keydown event where I set the value on a entity before inserting/updating this in the database.

in the click-method i also check if a specific key is pressed, if so i call BeginEdit and Focus. But it seems like EndEdit never gets called since the datagrid always has the flag isbeingedited set to true after the first edited cell and somehow it's preventing me from edit again. Is there a way to commit the editing in the keydown method which is only listening to the enter-key?

**XAML**

```
        <xcdg:DataGridControl Grid.Row="1" 
                              VerticalAlignment="Top"
                              MouseRightButtonUp="MyMethod_RightClick"
                              ItemsSource="{Binding ListOfObjects}"
                              AutoCreateColumns="False"
                              Height="1000"
                              NavigationBehavior="RowOnly">

            <xcdg:DataGridControl.Columns>
                <xcdg:Column FieldName="Name" IsMainColumn="False" MinWidth="500">
                    <xcdg:Column.CellEditor>
                        <xcdg:CellEditor>
                            <xcdg:CellEditor.EditTemplate>
                                <DataTemplate>
                                    <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                                        <TextBox x:Name="txtbox" KeyDown="txtbox_KeyDown" Text="{xcdg:CellEditorBinding}" />
                                    </StackPanel>
                                </DataTemplate>
                            </xcdg:CellEditor.EditTemplate>
                        </xcdg:CellEditor>
                    </xcdg:Column.CellEditor>
```

**XAML code-behind**

```
    private void MyMethod_RightClick(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        DataGridControl dataGrid = (DataGridControl)sender;
        MyObj myObj = (MyObj)dataGrid.CurrentItem;

        if (Keyboard.IsKeyDown(Key.E))
        {
            //i'm coming here all times i'm trying to edit records in one column but i'm only able to edit the first time i'm trying.
            dataGrid.BeginEdit();
            dataGrid.Focus();
            return;
        }
        //in case of no edit i do some other stuff...
    }


    private void txtbox_KeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.Key != Key.Enter) return;

        var txtboxvalue = ((TextBox)sender).DataContext.ToString();
        //do stuff and
        //set value on entity property and update record in db...
    }
```

Comment: Could you add some code? It is a little tough to imagine what you are trying to do/ where you are running into issues

Comment: @GordonAllocman I've edited my post. Thanks for your comment.